# Using CSS Variables in Chrome 29+

Tags: css, google-chrome, flags, css-variables

My Chrome browser just switched from version 28 to version 29. Once it switched over, my css3 code stopped working in the new version and I was wondering if anyone knew how to resolve the issue, without having to set my browser back to version 28?

**UPDATE Chrome 30** transitioning from Chrome 29 to Chrome 30 killed CSS Variables as well. The *Enable experimental WebKit features* flag is no longer an option.

I have been using experimental WebKit features, specifically CSS Variables. The following functionality is what I specifically want working again:

```
:root { 
  -webkit-var-Darkest: #3d0305;
  -webkit-var-Lightest: #EDD08C;
  -webkit-var-Light: #a98b46;
  -webkit-var-Cool: #38fcce;
  -webkit-var-Dark: #79161d;

  color: -webkit-var(Darkest);
  border-color: -webkit-var(Darkest);
  background-color: -webkit-var(Light);
}
```

Previously all I had to do to use CSS Variables was to enable the flag (see following image)

[image: Enable experimental WebKit features option]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So, after reading [code.google.com](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164139) in attempt to find a solution, I've discovered that they had been planning on removing this feature from the "experimental WebKit features" and supporting the CSS3 standard, removing the necessity of the `-webkit-` vendor prefix.

I assumed that this meant it was implemented in Chrome 29. So, changing the above code to the following resolved the issue:

```css
:root {
  var-Darkest: #3d0305;
  var-Lightest: #EDD08C;
  var-Light: #a98b46;
  var-Cool: #38fcce;
  var-Dark: #79161d;

  color: var(Darkest);
  border-color: var(Darkest);
  background-color: var(Light);
}
```

**UPDATE Chrome 30** In what appears to be a transition from **ending the use of WebKit** to Chromium's Blink, there is a **different flag that needs to be enabled** called *Enable experimental Web platform features*. An [Article at chromium.org](http://www.chromium.org/blink/runtime-enabled-features) had the solution.

[image: *Enable experimental Web Platform features* option]

**UPDATE Chrome 34**
The [CSS Variables spec.](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-variables/) has changed yet again. There were also other issues specific to the old code. I didn't update on this answer, because it was a rather different question. Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23370966/1992129) for more on the issue.